# cannot write a space using ofstream, but endl works fine

Tags: c++, ofstream, endl

Okay, this may seem a simple question; but I can't seem to find an answer to it. My code is as follows:

```
void writeFile(int grid[9][9]) {
   ofstream fout ("myGame2.txt");
   if (fout.is_open()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            fout << grid[i][j] << ' ';
         }
      }
      fout.close();
   }
}
```

This produces a file full of gibberish:

```
‷′″‰‰‰‱‵‹‶‰‰″‰′‰‰‸‸‰‰‰‱‰‰‰′‰‷‰‶‵‴‰′‰‰‰‴′‰‷″‰‰‰‵‰‹″‱‰‴‰‵‰‰‰‷‌​‰‰‰″‴‰‰‱‰″‰‰‶‹″′‰‰‰‷‌​‱‹'
```

But if I replace the space character with an endl, it outputs just fine.

```
fout << grid[i][j] << endl;
```

So my question becomes, how do I output my array to the file, and separate the integers with a space instead of an endl.

Also, if there is a location that explains this in greater detail, please feel free to link it. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a space in double quotes instead of single? (as in a string instead of a char) ?

Comment: @John3136 Yes, I have replaced ' ' with " ". I get the same results.

Comment: What do you mean by gibberish, exactly?

Comment: @rici The following text is produced when the code is executed. '‷′″‰‰‰‱‵‹‶‰‰″‰′‰‰‸‸‰‰‰‱‰‰‰′‰‷‰‶‵‴‰′‰‰‰‴′‰‷″‰‰‰‵‰‹″‱‰‴‰‵‰‰‰‷‰‰‰″‴‰‰‱‰″‰‰‶‹″′‰‰‰‷‱‹'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the IDE you're using, ending a file without an endl can cause problems.
Solution:

```
void writeFile(int grid[9][9]) {
   ofstream fout ("myGame2.txt");
   if (fout.is_open()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            fout << grid[i][j] << ' ';
         }
      }
      fout << endl;
      fout.close();
   }
}
```

Or if you want it to print out like a grid instead of a single line of text:

```
 void writeFile(int grid[9][9]) {
       ofstream fout ("myGame2.txt");
       if (fout.is_open()) {
          for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                fout << grid[i][j] << ' ';
             }
             fout << endl;
          }
          fout.close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: That was it, not ending the file with an endl was the problem. Thank you very much.